# VBA: Excel evaluating incorrectly

Tags: vba, excel

I have been hitting my head against the wall on why excel is evaluating something like 4 > 0 to be false...

In vba I am applying the following R1C1 forumla:

```
=IF(AND(RC[-5]>R1C15,RC[-4]>2*R1C15,RC[-3]>3*R1C15),""CORE"",""-"")
```

which when the macro is run, turns into:

```
=IF(AND(I2>$O$1,J2>2*$O$1,K2>3*$O$1),"CORE","-")
```

However, if we look at the screenshot of at row 2
I2, J2, K2, are all set to the value of 4 which is greater than O1 value of 0, but excel evaluates it as false.

[image]

Why? Both the fields are formatted as numbers?

full vba snippet:

```
Public Sub FormatCore()
    Rows("1:1").Select
    With ActiveWindow
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    End With
    Range("N2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC[-5]>R1C15,RC[-4]>2*R1C15,RC[-3]>3*R1C15),""CORE"",""-"")"
    Range("N3").Select
    Range("N2").Select
    Dim total_rows As Double
    total_rows = Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2: N" & total_rows)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try a cleaner VBA code code snippet: it does the job right:

```
Public Sub FormatCore()
    Dim total_rows As Double
    total_rows = Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("N2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC[-5]>R1C15,RC[-4]>2*R1C15,RC[-3]>3*R1C15),""CORE"",""-"")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2: N" & total_rows)
End Sub
```

Hope this will help.

***Note*** regarding the other solution and comments made and then deleted by the member @dashnick: the expression `J2>(2*$O$1)` is equivalent to `J2>2*$O$1` because the multiplication takes precedence, followed by logical operation, thus the parenthesis (as suggested by that member) are just optional; the solution will work without them.

Comment: @dashnick: Please DO NOT downvote my solution based on your erroneous assumption. The solution works fine with the original formula because the order of operation would be: multiplications first, then logical operations, thus your added parenthesis are just optional. Best regards,

Comment: @dashnick OK, no problem. Regards,